# Api response is null when consumed, with django and vue

Tags: python, django, vue.js, axios

Im using my api from the rest framework, when I got to the URL from the api it shows's it correct. But when I consume it the response seems to be null.
Im hosting both project (front vuejs and back django) in diferents ports (8080 and 8000, respectively). CORS are allowed.

I've tried with another tools like fetch or jquery and seems to be the same.

Js:

```js
export class APIService {
    contructor() {}

    get_user_id(){
        const url = `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user-id/`;
        return axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response); // For testing
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

Django api view, for that url:

```
class UserIdLoggedView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        return Response({
            'id': user.id,
        })
```

For this case I didn't need a serializer.

This is how the django rest shows it:

```
    {    HTTP 200 OK
    Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
    Content-Type: application/json
    Vary: Accept

    {
        "id": 1
    }
```

And this is the output of the response from the console (just the data part)

```
data:
   id: null
```

Instead of return id=1 as expected it return null.

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing Django's cookies along with your request? Or that you're testing with a logged user?

Comment: Im logged in the django port 8000.  Im not sure what you mean by the django cookies, the session middleware is active.

Answer (score 1):

why are you using two return statements in get_user_id? You hit the first return statement and it doesn't wait for the promise to be fulfilled. Basically, you send the get request but don't wait for the response. Also, I would recommend creating a base instance of axios as a vue plugin.